# This post does not meet our quality standards.

Tags: support, quality-filter

I try to post question but I always get the message:
This post does not meet our quality standards.

For example: 
I try to understand why by definition

$[c0,c1,...cn]=[c0,[c1,...cn]]$ and also
$[c0,c1,...cn]=[c0,c1,...c(n-2),[c(n-1),cn]]$  .

But not 
$[c0,c1,...cn]=[c0,c1,[c2,...cn]]$ for example.

or this:

P is a prime such that $q=p+2$ is also a prime.
I need to prove that there is an integer a such that $p|a^2-q$ if and only if there is b such that $q|b^2-p$.

Comment: See here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3038/quality-standards and here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5104/message-about-quality-standards

Comment: And here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8699/the-your-question-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards-thing  and a longer list here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quality-filter

Answer (score 0):

There is an automated filter on questions, as explained at the links in the comments. The algorithm is undisclosed, but from published information it is known to test for things like message being very short, containing forbidden strings, and not containing enough (in number, density, or some other metric) of parseable English words.   There is also some testing for capitalization of words or other indicators that the sentences are approximately grammatical.

Questions like the first example that are mostly LaTeX code with a few words around can trigger the "too short" and "too few English words" type of criteria.  The second example is longer but contains only one English word more than five characters long.